# How can I get events from video/broadcast object?

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie to OIPF/JavaScript. And this question is OIPF specific.

I have a video/broadcast object.

On my `ready` I did this.

```
var theControl;

function onPlayStateChange_(state, error) {
    console.log("onPlayStateChange(" + state + ", " + error + ")");
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    theControl = document.getElementById("theControl");
    theControl.onPlayStateChange = onPlayStateChange_;
}
```

When I do `setChannel(..)` or `stop()`, I got no events.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where is `theControl` element ? What is `onPlayStateChange` event ?

Comment: theControl is `video/broadcast` element defined in the document.

Comment: -Jin, Can we have a fiddle or executable demo ?

Comment: @Rayon Sorry my OIPF application is targeting STB.

Answer (score 1):

i know it's a pretty old question and i guess you already resolved your problem but it looks like you didn't do anything wrong.

You could also listen for `PlayStateChange` event like this :

```
theControl.addEventListener("PlayStateChange", () => {
    console.log("onPlayStateChange");
});
```

And you could also listen for `ChannelChangeSucceeded` or `ChannelChangeError` events in the same way.

If you're not receiving those events, you probably have something wrong with oipf integration on your device and should try [MIT xperts suite](http://itv.mit-xperts.com/hbbtvtest/channels/) on it to validate that.